# Attention seeking cat refusing attention when given

Tags: cats, psychology

I have a new cat that I have adopted, Sid (6mo). Pouf (5yrs), a previous cat, passed away, and I got Sid as a replacement to give Emma (7 yrs) some companionship, to which she didn't take well (Emma is quite solitary and while she does spend some time with Sid, it's usually accompanied with hissing).

Sid is *extremely* vocal. There is almost never a time where he is not screaming, moaning, etc. He will figure 8 around legs which is very distracting as it will often trip me up while trying to walk. He will knock things off of tables, get in my way while I'm trying to get things done (walk on keyboards, stop me from drinking/eating by getting between me and the food) These are all very much attention seeking behaviours.

Sometimes, he will take to play, sometimes, he will take to cuddles, but sometimes, nothing seems to appease him. I don't know what to do at this point. He used to bring toys to me to indicate play (and even play fetch), but he no longer does that.

He loves being outside, and he's often begging to go out. He's perfectly happy out there on his own murdering small fowl and butterflies. As soon as he sees me out there, it's nothing but noise again.

It seems he only does this when I'm around, but any attempts to appease this attention seeking behaviour doesn't work. Ignoring it does nothing, he will go on for an entire 8 hour workday.

Vet checkups appear fine. He was found appearing to be abandoned fairly early by the mother, but we can't tell why - he has mild pica (likes to suck on sheets) as a result, but it's improving with time. He is neutered.

I don't know what to do at this point, as the noise is becoming deafening and making it impossible to focus. Is there anything I may have missed here that could be an issue?

Edit: I'm not sure if this is relevant, but he's very interested in water. He'll watch the water come out of a sink as long as I'm willing to leave it running. He will not drink from the shared water bowl, but will drink water from literally any other source (my cups, he has his own dedicated water cup on the counter, outside sources that appear less than healthy)